# How to login to discord with beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, discord

I am trying to use beautiful soup to send messages to somebody every so often. This can not be a bot as it has to work in DM's. However in order to get to the page to DM somebody I need to login first. I have looked into HTTP Post but it can not find the form data to use the post method. How could I, with BeautifulSoup, get past this first login page. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = requests.get("https://discord.com/channels/@me/727172129799405609")
src = website.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I recieve the prettified code for this page, I can't see the form inputs anywhere. Is this normal? I am just assuming that I am on the discord login page but this may not be the case and this may be the reason I can't find form data to submit.

Comment: I think you probably want to use Selenium instead of BeautifulSoup + requests. That would make things a little easier for you to use the login page.

Comment: @DaneWhite Yes I did consider this, but would I be able to use selenium and have it running on a vps such as heroku so i can leave it running while my computer is off? Don't ask why

Comment: @InstaPage login page of this site is protected by reCaptcha.

Comment: Selenium can be run browser-less on a server. It also looks like there's a discord.py open source API client, and there seems to be a number of open source discord bots around that make use of selenium and/or discord.py.

Comment: @Dane White Ok.